# iPhone Website preview in Windows & Ubuntu

Tags: iphone

I'm using iPhone simulator in Mac for iPhone web devlopment with jqTouch. I want to know , how to check web design for iPhone with Windows or Ubuntu. I tried [iPhone Air](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&marketplaceid=1&offeringid=10250) but I don't like it. It's too small. Another tool or websites available for iPhone Web Development with Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, As Safari Mobile and the desktop Version using nearly the same version of WebKit, Just download Safari, and size the window to fit your site or write a JavaScript to set the size to 320x480 pixels, It is really that simple :)

Unfortunately I don't know any WebKit based Browser for Linux.

Comment: aror is a webkit browser. Yes, I need to resize winodws but Aror browser can't make iPhone Agent detection like safari. That is a bad. So, only way for windows it Safari ? Any others ?